# javafx import cannot be resolved in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, fxml

I am starting an assignment and just installed javafx from the Eclipse marketplace, after I installed and created a javafx project with fxml however in main the imports are showing errors saying "the import javafx cannot be resolved". I am new to Java and Eclipse and have tried to search for similar questions but they all seem to be different cases.

I would appreciate any help thank you.

Below is the code, and all the imports are showing errors:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = (BorderPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Student.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

I have figured that it is the library JavaFx SDK which is not able to be added to the project, is anyone good with Eclipse can help solve this problem? I tried configure build path and removing the JavaFx SDK and readding, still does not work.

Comment: What version of java are you using?

Comment: javase-11 seems that the library JavaFx sdk cannot be added to my project, have no idea how to fix this. Tried removing and readding, still does not work

Comment: Check this out https://openjfx.io/

Comment: does it work if you try to `import java.util.List;`  ?

Comment: You could also use an older version of java which has javafx included.

Comment: @MikeNakis this import works

Comment: @Juan why, was the comment so totally off the mark?  I am asking because I have seen situations where all imports seem to fail due to an unconfigured / misconfigured JDK.  So, I thought it would be best to eliminate that simple possibility before going on a wild goose chase.

Comment: @Juan may I ask which version is it?

Comment: @MikeNakis Honestly I really thought you had targetted the wrong question. I didn't mean any offence.

Comment: I use java 8 which, though java 10 should also come with javafx. It is as of java 11 that it has been separated from the distribution.

Comment: Read the instructions in [Getting Started with JavaFX 11](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/)—specifically the _JavaFX and Eclipse_ section. The JavaFX modules were separated from the JDK in Java 11 and now must be pulled in like any other dependency.

Comment: @Juan no problem, I did not take any offense at all, I always accept the possibility that I may be terribly wrong on any given thing that I say.

Comment: @Juan I tried java-1.8 and java.10 both give me the same errors, I just want to start my lab as soon as possible, would using a different IDE be the quickest solution, any recommendation which IDE to use that is more user-friendly?

Comment: I use it with Eclipse where i also installed the e(fx)clipse plugin.

Comment: @juan I just added the jfxrt.jar manually and the errors go away however when I run the main, it's still giving me "Error: Could not find or load main class application.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application"

Comment: You shouldn't add it manually.  This link has a tutorial for both netbeans and eclipse. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javafx/javafx_environment.htm

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 main steps to check: (There are other ways to do this but this is one way)

In your case I think the issue is in the 4th step.

1. Make sure you installed javafx from the marketplace, in case of eclipse it is eclipse marketplace.
2. Download and unzip the appropriate Java SDK folder for you system from here: https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/
3. On your project, configure build path, add a user library, new , then add external JARs, then choose all the .jar files on your Java SDK folder then add that library to your project
4. Run your project as a normal java application (so that you don't have to search for it later in the configurations) then choose run as, configure the run and you will find an arguments tab, add this to your VM arguments but replace what is inside the double quotations with the file path of your Java SDK lib folder- make sure it's the lib folder, inside the Java SDK. Here is what you will paste: --module-path "\path\to\javafx-sdk-11\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml